# Eclipse Orion: Multiple files open

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-orion

I just started using Eclipse Orion. While most of it works really well, it seems impossible to keep multiple files open at a time. In the same way files are displayed as tabs in eclipse. Whenever I open a new file in Orion, the old one disappears. Having all opened files available as tabs would make it much easier to switch back and forth. Is this feature not available in Orion or did I just miss something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear, based on this quote, that the intention is to use multiple browser tabs:

> Unlike other attempts at creating browser-based development tools, **this is not an IDE running in a single tab**. Links work and can be shared. You can **open a file in a new tab**.

source: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion